# CNTK's Data Parallel Training latest MS-MPI version 8.1

Tags: cntk

CNTK's documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Multiple-GPUs-and-machines) says Microsoft MPI (MS-MPI) version 7 needs to be installed for data parallel training.

Will latest n' greatest CNTK version 2.2 work with latest n' greatest MS-MPI version 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

The versions suggested in the documentation work and are tested. Other versions may work but they aren't being tested. So you could try. My hunch is if you build from source it will work and if you use the binaries you will need the version we recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried MS-MPI Version 8.1.12438.1084 and it works with my https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/GPU-1bit-SGD/cntk-2.2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl